# Xamarin: libmonosgen-2.0.dylib: required code signature missing on MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, multipeer-connectivity

I'm using MultiPeer framework from [a working code-only approach](https://github.com/lobrien/MultipeerConnectivity/blob/74d7bebbae91c88a1fd5f0614a6ef31cc6c6c8b6/Program.cs) and moving it [into a MVVM structure](https://github.com/makerofthings7/XamarinMPBug) and am getting the exception below.

I'm using Mac OS High Sierra on two different computers, each with an iPhone [running my MVVM instance.](https://github.com/makerofthings7/XamarinMPBug)

I have closely inspected the code-only approach, and am even using properties (not fields), within in an instance.  This seems like a Xamarin binding or linker issue.

**NearbyDevicesViewController.cs/MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser - BROKEN**

```
public partial class NearbyDevicesViewController : UITableViewController
{
    public string myPhoneName { get; set; }
    public  MCPeerID myPeerID { get; set; }
    public const string SERVICE_STRING = "AELP";
    public MCSession Session { get; set; }

    List<PeerMonitorStatus> CachedPeerStatus = new List<PeerMonitorStatus>();

    public NearbyDevicesViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        myPhoneName = "A" + UIKit.UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Name; // Adding A prefix incase numeric isn't allowed (it's a problem in Windows NETBIOS... so maybe also here?)
        MyPhoneStatus.MyPeerID =  myPhoneName;
        myPeerID = new MCPeerID(myPhoneName);

        Session = new MCSession(myPeerID);
        Session.Delegate = new ChatSessionDelegate(Session);
        //--------------------------------Advertiser----------------------------------------------------
        var emptyDict = new NSDictionary();
        AppDelegate.advertiser = new MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(myPeerID, emptyDict, SERVICE_STRING);
        AppDelegate.advertiser.Delegate = new MyNearbyAdvertiserDelegate(this);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting advertising...");
        AppDelegate.advertiser.StartAdvertisingPeer();
        MyPhoneStatus.IsAdvertising = true;

        ////--------------------------------Browser------------------------------------------------------
        //AppDelegate.browser = new MCNearbyServiceBrowser(myPeerID, SERVICE_STRING);
        //AppDelegate.browser.Delegate = new MyBrowserDelegate(myPeerID, Session);

        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting browsing...");
        //AppDelegate.browser.StartBrowsingForPeers();
        //MyPhoneStatus.IsBrowsing = true;

        CachedPeerStatus.AddRange(AppDelegate.PeerHistoryMonitor.Values);
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return CachedPeerStatus.Count;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = new UITableViewCell(CGRect.Empty);
        var item = CachedPeerStatus[indexPath.Row];

        cell.TextLabel.Text = item.DisplayText;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

**AdvertiserController/MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser - WORKING**

```
public class AdvertiserController : DiscoveryViewController
{
    MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser advertiser;

    public AdvertiserController(string peerID) : base(peerID)
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        View = new DiscoveryView("Advertiser", this);
        var emptyDict = new NSDictionary();
        Status("Starting advertising...");

        advertiser = new MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(PeerID, emptyDict, SERVICE_STRING);
        advertiser.Delegate = new MyNearbyAdvertiserDelegate(this);
        advertiser.StartAdvertisingPeer();
    }
}
```

**MyNearbyAdvertiserDelegate.cs - BROKEN**

```
public  class MyNearbyAdvertiserDelegate : MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate
{
    MCSession session;

    public MyNearbyAdvertiserDelegate(NearbyDevicesViewController session)
    {
        this.session = session.Session;
    }

    public override void DidReceiveInvitationFromPeer(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser advertiser, MCPeerID peerID, NSData context, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserInvitationHandler invitationHandler)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Advertiser [" + session.MyPeerID.GetNativeHash() + "] will accept invite from " + peerID.DisplayName + " [" + peerID.GetNativeHash() + "]");

        MyPhoneStatus.LastInvitation = DateTime.UtcNow;

        MyPhoneStatus.ConnectedPeers.Clear();
        MyPhoneStatus.ConnectedPeers.AddRange(session.ConnectedPeers);

        invitationHandler(true, session); 
    }
}
```

**MyNearbyAdvertiserDelegate - WORKING**

```
class MyNearbyAdvertiserDelegate : MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate
{
    AdvertiserController parent;

    public MyNearbyAdvertiserDelegate(AdvertiserController parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public override void DidReceiveInvitationFromPeer(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser advertiser, MCPeerID peerID, NSData context, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserInvitationHandler invitationHandler)
    {
        parent.Status("Received Invite");
        invitationHandler(true, parent.Session);
    }
}
```

**Testing Environment**

I have two Mac+iPhone hardware combinations.  The problem occurs regardless of which machine is the advertiser.  Manual configuration within `NearbyDevicesViewController` is needed to alter if the code is running as a server or a browser.

When the server gets an invite via `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate`, the advertiser crashes with the exception below

**Visual Studio output**

```
Launched application 'net.agent7.AELP-MP' on '73' with pid 677
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D2774A07-619E-44C5-9137-526686F6769C/AELPMP.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Thread started:  #2
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D2774A07-619E-44C5-9137-526686F6769C/AELPMP.app/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D2774A07-619E-44C5-9137-526686F6769C/AELPMP.app/AELPMP.exe
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'ChatSessionDelegate.cs:18,1' to void AELPMP.ChatSessionDelegate.DidChangeState (MultipeerConnectivity.MCSession session, MultipeerConnectivity.MCPeerID peerID, MultipeerConnectivity.MCSessionState state) [0x00001].
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'ChatSessionDelegate.cs:25,46' to void AELPMP.ChatSessionDelegate.DidChangeState (MultipeerConnectivity.MCSession session, MultipeerConnectivity.MCPeerID peerID, MultipeerConnectivity.MCSessionState state) [0x00069].
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'MyNearbyAdvertiserDelegate.cs:18,1' to void AELPMP.MyNearbyAdvertiserDelegate.DidReceiveInvitationFromPeer (MultipeerConnectivity.MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser advertiser, MultipeerConnectivity.MCPeerID peerID, Foundation.NSData context, MultipeerConnectivity.MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserInvitationHandler invitationHandler) [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'MyNearbyAdvertiserDelegate.cs:14,1' to void AELPMP.MyNearbyAdvertiserDelegate..ctor (AELPMP.NearbyDevicesViewController session) [0x00008].
Starting advertising...
2018-03-14 17:14:35.852 AELPMP[677:249758] critical: Stacktrace:

2018-03-14 17:14:35.852 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2018-03-14 17:14:35.853 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0x00007>
2018-03-14 17:14:35.854 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.10.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
2018-03-14 17:14:35.855 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.10.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
2018-03-14 17:14:35.855 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:   at AELPMP.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00001] in /Users/lamont/Downloads/AELPMP/Main.cs:12
2018-03-14 17:14:35.856 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0001e] in <0a8ff55fca4d4370bf8503724a39a15f#C25D3657-4A8E-C9A0-B325-6976392E2CBB>:0
2018-03-14 17:14:35.857 AELPMP[677:249758] critical: 
Native stacktrace:

2018-03-14 17:14:35.891 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    0   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000101200664 mono_handle_native_crash + 224
2018-03-14 17:14:35.892 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    1   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010120d394 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 316
2018-03-14 17:14:35.892 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0000000185d73b50 _sigtramp + 52
2018-03-14 17:14:35.892 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    3   libxamarin-debug.dylib              0x0000000101519f94 xamarin_get_block_wrapper_creator + 52
2018-03-14 17:14:35.892 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    4   libxamarin-debug.dylib              0x000000010151dbd8 _ZL32get_method_block_wrapper_creatorP11_MonoMethodiPj + 260
2018-03-14 17:14:35.892 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    5   libxamarin-debug.dylib              0x000000010151da04 xamarin_get_delegate_for_block_parameter + 64
2018-03-14 17:14:35.893 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    6   AELPMP                              0x0000000100ba55f0 _ZL30native_to_managed_trampoline_8P11objc_objectP13objc_selectorPP11_MonoMethodP25MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserP8MCPeerIDP6NSDataS0_j + 848
2018-03-14 17:14:35.893 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    7   AELPMP                              0x0000000100ba5294 -[AELPMP_MyNearbyAdvertiserDelegate advertiser:didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:withContext:invitationHandler:] + 80
2018-03-14 17:14:35.893 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    8   MultipeerConnectivity               0x00000001a2080934 <redacted> + 180
2018-03-14 17:14:35.893 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000185acea54 <redacted> + 24
2018-03-14 17:14:35.893 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000185acea14 <redacted> + 16
2018-03-14 17:14:35.894 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000185adb698 <redacted> + 1016
2018-03-14 17:14:35.894 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001860f7344 <redacted> + 12
2018-03-14 17:14:35.894 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001860f4f20 <redacted> + 2012
2018-03-14 17:14:35.894 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000186014c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
2018-03-14 17:14:35.895 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000187ec0f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
2018-03-14 17:14:35.895 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    16  UIKit                               0x000000018f76d5c4 UIApplicationMain + 236
2018-03-14 17:14:35.895 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    17  libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib            0x000000010112fce0 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 368
2018-03-14 17:14:35.895 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    18  libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib            0x000000010111a1bc UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 44
2018-03-14 17:14:35.896 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    19  libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib            0x000000010111a17c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 172
2018-03-14 17:14:35.896 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    20  libAELPMP.exe.dylib                 0x0000000100bcbf80 AELPMP_Application_Main_string__ + 128
2018-03-14 17:14:35.896 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    21  libmscorlib.dll.dylib               0x0000000100dcb8e8 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 248
2018-03-14 17:14:35.896 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    22  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x00000001012104e0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 968
2018-03-14 17:14:35.897 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    23  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000101290620 do_runtime_invoke + 112
2018-03-14 17:14:35.897 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    24  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x00000001012939b0 do_exec_main_checked + 144
2018-03-14 17:14:35.897 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    25  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x00000001011f2274 mono_jit_exec + 268
2018-03-14 17:14:35.897 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    26  libxamarin-debug.dylib              0x000000010152ccd0 xamarin_main + 2220
2018-03-14 17:14:35.897 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    27  AELPMP                              0x0000000100ba9958 main + 96
2018-03-14 17:14:35.898 AELPMP[677:249758] critical:    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000185b3456c <redacted> + 4
2018-03-14 17:14:35.898 AELPMP[677:249758] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

**XCode output**
This is the output when I connect via Xcode and look at the device logs

```
Incident Identifier: 791E1B33-A22E-4684-8ADF-0E4F601E01FC
CrashReporter Key:   8168b2a05f10e5f21da37250e7a61b844de00385
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,1
Process:             AELPMP [263]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/99083856-91ED-46FF-A844-2E30F49014FF/AELPMP.app/AELPMP
Identifier:          net.agent7.AELP-MP
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           net.agent7.AELP-MP [413]


Date/Time:           2018-03-13 20:17:17.5692 -0400
Launch Time:         2018-03-13 20:17:17.4649 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.6 (15D100)
Baseband Version:    3.42.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: @rpath/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib | Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/99083856-91ED-46FF-A844-2E30F49014FF/AELPMP.app/AELPMP | Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find: | /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/99083856-91ED-46FF-A844-2E30F49014FF/AELPMP.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib: required code signature missing for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/99083856-91ED-46FF-A844-2E30F49014FF/AELPMP.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib' | 
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x000000010066ef48 __abort_with_payload + 8
1   dyld                            0x000000010066e71c abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100
2   dyld                            0x000000010066e748 fcntl + 0
3   dyld                            0x0000000100644498 dyld::fastBindLazySymbol+ 17560 (ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 0
4   dyld                            0x0000000100647714 dyld::_main+ 30484 (macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 7376
5   dyld                            0x000000010064121c _dyld_start + 68

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000006   x1: 0x0000000000000005   x2: 0x000000016f92e4b0   x3: 0x000000000000008b
    x4: 0x000000016f92e0b0   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x00000000000002e0
    x8: 0x0000000000000020   x9: 0x0000000000000009  x10: 0x67736f6e6f6d6269  x11: 0x642e302e322d6e65
   x12: 0x2f7070612e504d50  x13: 0x736f6e6f6d62696c  x14: 0x2e302e322d6e6567  x15: 0x000a2762696c7964
   x16: 0x0000000000000209  x17: 0x000000008000001f  x18: 0xfffffff00f0dd260  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x000000016f92e0b0  x21: 0x000000000000008b  x22: 0x000000016f92e4b0  x23: 0x0000000000000005
   x24: 0x0000000000000006  x25: 0x00000001004d0000  x26: 0x0000000100682000  x27: 0x0000000100681f88
   x28: 0x000000016f92fab0   fp: 0x000000016f92e080   lr: 0x000000010066e71c
    sp: 0x000000016f92e040   pc: 0x000000010066ef48 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x1004d0000 - 0x1004dffff AELPMP arm64  <cf358776c3b038b6b2ba40f0fce56323> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/99083856-91ED-46FF-A844-2E30F49014FF/AELPMP.app/AELPMP
0x100500000 - 0x10050ffff libAELPMP.exe.dylib arm64  <125e771584d2332084c3901961cd3b59> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/99083856-91ED-46FF-A844-2E30F49014FF/AELPMP.app/libAELPMP.exe.dylib
0x100524000 - 0x10052bfff libSystem.dll.dylib arm64  <e2f273739ebe391f961f97cb8573fdde> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/99083856-91ED-46FF-A844-2E30F49014FF/AELPMP.app/libSystem.dll.dylib
0x100640000 - 0x10067ffff dyld arm64  <477a8a1f098b3a80860d656a3f4918ea> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1006dc000 - 0x100857fff libmscorlib.dll.dylib arm64  <141d1723f765324bb687d89b93133a2b> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/99083856-91ED-46FF-A844-2E30F49014FF/AELPMP.app/libmscorlib.dll.dylib
0x100b38000 - 0x100b9bfff libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib arm64  <c208d3645de53ba59a7ff7179ff584bb> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/99083856-91ED-46FF-A844-2E30F49014FF/AELPMP.app/libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib

EOF
```

Comment: So... are we supposed to go through the entire codebase to see what's different between one version and the other? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the linked, working `code only approach` is a minimal complete verifiable example (right?).  My attempt to simply port the server which is failing. I'm hoping for some way to get more understanding of the iOS output.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Since this requires two nodes (server and client), how else would you suggest I create such an example?

Comment: Either post the C# Exception/Stacktrace or symbolize the native iOS crash using the msym from the build.

Comment: @SushiHangover I think I did post the C# exception from the first revision of the question through the current one. If more work is needed I'll do it. Not sure how to msym the iOS crash

Answer (score 2):

In a similar situation, I've found that deleting the output folders and cleaning before building again fixes this issue.

Right click on the Solution and select "Delete Output Folder"